# Code Igniter wont send emails to @hotmail addresses

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using the following code to send my emails upone registration - it works for all email addresses except from @hotmail.com / .co.uk.

```
'$email_address = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message =  'Welcome Member, <br /><br />


<p><a href="'.base_url().'site/activate/'.$lastId.'/" target="_blank">'.base_url().'site/activate/'.$lastId.'/</a></p>

';

$AdminEmail  = 'info@something.org';
$Subject  = 'Account Confirmation';

//@send_email($emailadderss,$Subject, $message, $AdminEmail, '');
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: noreply@something.com' . "\r\n";
$msg = @mail($email_address, $Subject, $message, $headers);
```

I am sure why this is and I cannot find any solutions upon searching the internet.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your email is probably in their spam folder.

Comment: It has nothing to do with CodeIgniter. You should remove the `@` from `@mail` it's suppressing any errors.

Comment: @relentless: mail doesn't issue any warnings, and only returns boolean false on error anyways. mail() has very little that can fail. either it hands the email off to the local smta/smtp server, or it doesn't. OP needs to check the mail server's logs to see what happened after PHP handed off the mail.

Comment: @MarcB - True, but there isn't much of a reason to suppress the errors. But, you're right, the mail server logs are the place to look.

Comment: I will check the mail logs and get back asap. regards

Comment: I am unable to find my error logs on 123-reg - there are none shown in the error section. I am unable to get to /var/log/maillog with it being a shared package.
I have added a SPF record that has had not difference to this issue.